# How to call a function from all components' componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a ReactJS based website. I'm using hooks if it makes a difference.

I'm writing some security code for anti forgery token etc. I would like to call a function automatically without implementing it page by page.

How to call a function from all components' componentDidMount? Is there a global event for it?

Right now doing this like this; but it is really complicated to follow all and implement this...

```
  componentDidMount() {
    token.Get();
  }
```

Comment: I'm guessing the `token.Get();` method yields the same result on all components. If I'm correct, couldn't you just use the context API and wrap it around your `App`?

Comment: it's not your answer but give you a idea
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hooks, you are using function components, and therefore do not have access to lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount`. To trigger an effect on mount and unmount, you would have to do something like

```
React.useEffect(() => token.Get(), [])
```

(https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

To define a global behaviour as you seem to want, you may be able to implement the behaviour at the root `App.js` level. You could also possibly create a higher order component to wrap every component that needs this behaviour, but it seems overkill for one line of code (https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically add a token to all your requests, it's easy to do so with `axios` like this:

`axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = YOUR_TOKEN;`

See [axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#config-defaults) for details.